# Spotlight has issues indexing files, Finder tag not working

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight, macos-ventura

When I got a new MacBook Pro M1 running Ventura I restored all Data from TimeMachine to it. After it I found that Spotlight search doesn't run properly. Playing with mdutil fixed it.
Now I still face the issue that files are not listed in color tags summary in Finder though they are tagged. When I dug deeper into it I found that Spotlight is not indexing any meta data from any file, except the ones starting with "kMDItemFS...".

So I have a file (test.txt) tagged purple, purple is called "Test".
Calling `xattr -l test.txt` outputs correctly this:

```
com.apple.FinderInfo: 
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags: bplist00?VTest
3
```

But, when calling `mdls test.txt` the output doesn't show the tag property:

```
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 6
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 3
kMDItemFSName              = "test.txt"
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 0
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 501
kMDItemFSSize              = 0
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
```

When I copy the file to another machines, calling `mdls test.txt` outputs a lot more meta data including the color tag:

```
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions      = "test.txt"
com_apple_metadata_modtime             = 713980260
kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking     = 2023-08-17 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate_Ranking = 2023-08-17 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentType                     = "public.plain-text"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2023-08-17 16:16:17 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking               = 2023-08-17 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                     = "test.txt"
kMDItemDocumentIdentifier              = 0
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 2023-08-17 15:51:00 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode                   = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags                   = 6
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon                 = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                     = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden             = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery                  = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                         = 3
kMDItemFSName                          = "test.txt"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                     = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID                  = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID                   = 501
kMDItemFSSize                          = 0
kMDItemFSTypeCode                      = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking         = 2023-08-17 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemKind                            = "Reines Textdokument"
kMDItemLogicalSize                     = 0
kMDItemPhysicalSize                    = 0
kMDItemUserTags                        = (
    Test
)
```

It looks like Spotlight doesn't index the files correctly. I already tried these command

```
mdutil -i off /
mdutil -i on /
mdutil -E
mdutil -X
```

in various sequences, without success.
What can I do else?